# 'NSInvalidArgumentException': unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d25aa0'

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on an Tableview (Master/Detail) template for IOS 6, I am getting the following error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewController saveAcctData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d25aa0'

here is my code: what does this mean? Any help would be appreciated.
thank you.

```
- (IBAction)saveAcctData {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [array addObject:AcctName.text];
    [array addObject:AcctNum.text];
    [array addObject:DayDue.text];
    [array addObject:paymnt.text];
    [array addObject:remBalance.text];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *plistPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.plist"];

    [array writeToFile:plistPath atomically: true];
}
```

Comment: Search your project for `saveAcctData:`, remove parameters  if there are any and remove the colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be calling the method from somewhere as saveAcctData: (with a colon), but your method implementation doesn't have a colon.

Comment: thank you, I didn't find the saveAcctData with a colon, but I do appreciate your answer. when I find the answer I will post it. thanks so much for your help! Regards,

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel, well, that's what the error message is saying, so it must be being called somewhere.

Comment: there is one place that is true ... but I don't know how to correct it. In the Connections Inspector

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel, just make you method saveAcctData:(id)sender

Comment: I deleted everything, and tried again... same issues. I even tried to do it manually and that didn't work. But, thanks for helping, I do appreciate it.

Comment: the solution to correcting this issue was to add the same button in the DetailViewController, I don't know why, but it worked, now on to more issues with my plist not actually updating. :(

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel, this sounds like a very bad solution -- it's really hard to tell what's going on, but I think you have something seriously messed up in the overall structure of your app. I'd be glad to take a look at it if you can send it to me.